# Can't insert entity with foreign key in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm building Backend for Mobile Application with ASP.NET MVC Framework.
I have two Objects:

```
public class CarLogItem : EntityData
{
    public CarLogItem(): base()
    {
        Time = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    public int RPM { get; set; }
    public int Speed { get; set; }  
    public int RunTime { get; set; }
    public int Distance { get; set; }
    public int Throttle { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Trip")]
    public String Trip_id { get; set; }

    // Navigation property
    public TripItem Trip { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class TripItem : EntityData
{
    public TripItem() : base()
    {
        UserId = User.GetUserSid();
        StartTime = DateTime.Now;
        logItems = new List<CarLogItem>();
    }
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public List<CarLogItem> logItems {get;set;}
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
}
```

and I have controller, which add new CarLogItem to database.

```
public class CarLogItemController : TableController<CarLogItem>
{
    // POST tables/CarLogItem
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostCarLogItem(CarLogItem item)
    {
        var lastItem = db.CarLogItems.OrderByDescending(x => x.Time).FirstOrDefault();
        //lastItem = (Query().Where(logitem => true).OrderBy(logitem => logitem.Time)).Last();

        //checking if lastItem.Trip isn't null because
        //  I have entities with Trip field is null, but all of them should have it.
        if (lastItem != null && lastItem.Trip != null && item.RunTime > lastItem.RunTime)
        {
            item.Trip = lastItem.Trip;
        }

        //In order to test adding of new TripItem entity to database
        //  I compare item.RunTime with 120, so it always true
        else if (lastItem == null || item.RunTime < 120) // < lastItem.RunTime)
        {
            var newTrip = new TripItem();
            item.Trip = newTrip;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        CarLogItem current = await InsertAsync(item);

        return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to add new CarLogItem with Trip = null it's ok, but when Trip is particular object it fails with following Exception:

> The entity submitted was invalid: Validation error on property 'Id': The Id field is required

How properly to add new CarLogItem with nested TripItem?

Comment: It's apparent that you need to set the `Id` property, but you've given no code that demonstrates anything has an `Id` property.

Comment: What is `TripItem` primary key? I cannot see it in your model.

Comment: Both my entities inherits Id property from EntityData

Comment: @МихаилБабушкин could you show EntityData class?

Comment: @AndreiM [from Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.windowsazure.mobile.service.entitydata.aspx)
Id property marked with [CompilerGeneratedAttribute], so I suppose it's do all magic by itself, like it do for CarLogItem's Id property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to populate the Id property on your TripItem, e.g.

```
var newTrip = new TripItem(){ Id = Guid.NewGuid() }
```

Comment: Isn't it setting in base Constructor of EntityData?
I'm not setting Id for CarLogItem and after inserting
 
        CarLogItem current = await InsertAsync(item);

it returns CarLogItem with Id

Comment: I added Id initialization to TripItem Constructor
`Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();` and now it works. But I still don't understand why MVC generate Id for CarlogItem automatically but don't do that for TripItem

Comment: It could be the way the DB is set up and whether it autogenerates and ID value

Answer (score 0):

You need a primary key field in every entity class, like `Id` or `CarLogItemId` (ClassName + "Id"). Or just have a property with `[Key]` attribute:

```
[Key]
public string/int/Guid/any-db-supported-type MyProp { get; set; }
```

> Entity Framework relies on every entity having a key value that it
>   uses for tracking entities. One of the conventions that code first
>   depends on is how it implies which property is the key in each of the
>   code first classes. That convention is to look for a property named
>   “Id” or one that combines the class name and “Id”, such as “BlogId”.
>   The property will map to a primary key column in the database.

Please see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/data/jj591583.aspx#Key) for more details.

---

I also suspect this to be a problem:

```
public Lazy<CarLogItem> logItems { get; set; }
```

You don't have to mark navigation property as `Lazy<>`. It is already lazy (unless you have configuration that disables lazy loading). Please try to remove `Lazy<>` and see if it works this way.

Comment: Yes, actually it should be List<>. I was just trying to use Lazy, but it didn't make a sense. It's same exception in both cases.
I edited post.